# Why does ndiff (Python 3) report differences in three different ways

Tags: python

Environment: Mageia 7, Python 3.7
I maintain a contact list for my charity, and produce a monthly list of changes, so that members who need to broadcast a message can maintain their lists easily. (I could use sdiff, but because my successor may be a Windows user, I implemented a python3 script that will also run under Windows).
I notice ndiff reports differences in three ways:

```
- Peter Mxxxxxk,pl.xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx,01300 000000,07948 000000,SW  
+ Peter Mxxxxxk,xxxxxxx.membership@xxx.xxx.uk,01300 000000,07948 000000,SW  

- David Middxxxxn,davidmiddxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx,01300 000000,07776 000000,TR  
?                                                                          ^^  
+ David Middxxxxn,davidmiddxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx,01300 000000,07776 000000,WK  
?                                                                          ^^  

- Mary Txxxxxl,,01300 000000,,WK  
+ Mary Txxxxxl,mary@xxxxxxx.xxx,01300 000000,,WK  
?              ++++++++++++++++
```

Why? It makes further processing very difficult when there may or may not be a ? after a line.
Sorry, I should have explained....
I was hoping to find the following:
- in front of a line that was deleted
+ in front of a line that was added
-  followed by ? followed by +  followed by ? to indicate changes (as per second example)
That way, I can point out contacts who have been deleted, who have been added or whose contact details have been changed.

Comment: try reading about [`SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) and using [`get_opcodes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes). I find it useful and handy to analyse and report differences between strings

Comment: Also, is your question simply *why a library works in a certain way*? if so, the simplest answer is becasue that's how it's implemented. If you find it inconvinient you may seek other resources. You might want to rephrase your question for showing how you try to process that data and ask for help on doing that better, or ask for alternatives (which might be offtopic...). Here you simply show the results but not the code of how you use it

Comment: You might find [csv-diff](https://github.com/simonw/csv-diff/blob/master/README.md) useful.

Comment: Alasdair, thanks - I can see from the JSON output that's exactly what I need - now to learn how to get that into a better format!